# Xcode App Submission Error: Client unable to connect to server

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, application-loader

I'm trying to submit an app to the app store and I am constantly running in this error:

```
"The sessions status is FAILED and the error description is : Client unable to connect to server. Check UDD and Firewall(15)"
```

I tried everything I found here on stack exchange from restarting my computer, through using Xcode and Application loader. Nothing helped and I am constantly getting this error.

Guys. I tried restarting Xcode and the machine....

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by uploading from another Mac with application loader, however also on a different Network. Then it worked smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

I restarted my router and the submission went through!

It was odd because I had uploaded 2 similar apps successfully just before the issue occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Read System and Network Requirements in this DOC 
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf other wise try  to submit in another MAC.